# Google Chrome is not rendering properly my CSS layout after Version 44.0.2403.107 m

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Mozilla Firefox this works properly and in Chrome until this new version.

```
.company_color{
    color:#f04848;
}

<select>
    <option  value="">Company</option>
<option class="company_color" value="test">test</option>
..
<option value="test500">test500</option>
</select>
```

It should color the text with red when option class is "company_color". But when there are many companies (more than 300 in a pure test. Even less in a production test) chrome just ignores the colouring function. But this just started to happen in this new version.

Does someone have a solution or this will be a chrome restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, google chrome is disabling the style of options inside selects that have more than 300 options. There's not much to do.